# object is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, forms, select

I made a pretty huge script for a form and everything works fine except that my select with onchange() doesnt work at all, but only in THIS script. If I try to do it on a blank page (just put a script tag, put my js inside of it, put my html code with my select tag, etc...everything works fine).

So my question is : Why is my function modele isn't working at all? Is there any kind of issu inside my head tag? Thx!

P.S. This is what I get in the console : Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

```
   <head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>


    function modele(form) {
        var x = form.marque.selectedIndex;
        alert(x);
    }
</script>
    <style>
        [...]
    </style>
</head>
```

inside my body :

```
<form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" id="credit">
[...]
<td><label for="marque">Marque :</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="marque" name="marque" onChange="modele(this.form)">
                            <option></option>
                            <option>Acuras</option>
                            <option>Hondas</option>
                            <option></option>
                            <option></option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><label for="modele">Modele :</label></td>
                    <td><select id="modele" name="modele">
                            <option></option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
[...]
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you've given the `<select>` element the id "modele". Change either that or the name of the function. The browser is overriding the binding of the function to the global name "modele" with a reference to the DOM node for the `<select>`.

Comment: Great job! It is now working perfectly, thanks! In the future, I will remember that. ( I will accept your answer in about 10 mins )

Answer (score 0):

There are two other objects with the name 'modele'.  The first is the id of the second select tag and the second is the name of the second select is also 'modele'.

Try changing both to something else or change the name of the function to something else to make it work.

Comment: The value of the "name" attribute won't cause a problem.